# MOSFET body diode current rating vs Schottky diode

Tags: mosfet, diodes, losses

How is it possible that a MOSFET's body diode in a TO-220 package, such as the N-channel IRL3803 or P-channel IRF4905, has a much higher average/continuous current rating than a high-current Schottky diode in a larger TO-247 package, such as the VS-40CPQ060-N3?

One would expect that a MOSFET which is in a smaller package and that has a higher forward voltage drop at a given current, would have a lower current rating than a Schottky diode, which has a lower forward voltage drop and in a package with a larger surface area.

Comment: Look at the conditions for both ratings.  The diode is rated with a case temp held at 120 C, and the FET is rated with a case temp held at 25 C.  Neither is necessarily realistic in practice.